# BottomSheet does not collapse when I press the Back Button

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

My `bottomSheet` behaves correctly except in this situation. When I return to the activity via 'back button', I want the `bottomSheet` to collapse and I thought the code below would do the trick, but it doesn't work. What could be the cause ? (*I confirmed with debugger that it reaches the statement*)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
}
```

the same line works fine when it returns via `finish()`:

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

    mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
}
```

Comment: `when it returns via finish()` ? can you elaborate on that ?

Comment: oops, sorry, bad paste, fixed the 2nd code snippet

Comment: It's too late to answer but anyway, try this inside onBackPressed method : `mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);`

Answer (score 2):

If your dialog has `setCancelable(true)`, back button will not trigger the `onbackpressed()`, you can try this

I have a class call BottomSheetFragmentDialog which is extend from BottomSheetDialogFragment and I have `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)` inside the `onCreateDialog` Method also overrdie the `onCancel()`

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
    return dialog
}

override fun onCancel(dialog: DialogInterface) {
    super.onCancel(dialog)
    Toast.makeText(context, "Break Point Here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler solution.

Don't have to override onBackPressed method, just have to remove `setCancelable(true)` and add `bottomSheetDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)` when you initialise the bottomSheetDialog.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code onBackPressed() methode

```
behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: This does not work because the onBackPressed() method is not called.